# React useLayoutEffect equivalent in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do we mimic the functionality of [`useLayoutEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) in a class component?

Suppose our functional component is

```
function MyFuncComponent() {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    runSideEffect();
  });
}
```

Assuming this particular side effect requires no cleanup, is this following code equivalent?

```
class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    runSideEffect();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    runSideEffect();
  }
}
```

From the doc, it seems they are not exactly equivalent, as multiple scheduled `useLayoutEffect()`s are flushed in between consecutive renders, but `componentDidUpdate()`s aren't. Is this understanding correct and if so, how do we mimic `useLayoutEffect()`?

> Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

Comment: Try getSnapshotBeforeUpdate. it should probably work.

Answer (score 3):

according to the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

> If you’re migrating code from a class component, note `useLayoutEffect` fires in the same phase as `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. However, we recommend starting with `useEffect` first and only trying `useLayoutEffect` if that causes a problem.

So if you want your side effect to run in a class component with the same behaviour you gotta use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` like you thought. The difference between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` is that `useEffect` only runs after the DOM has been updated (the effect will run after the render is committed to the screen). `useLayoutEffect` will trigger the effect right after the DOM mutations are computed. Therefore, updates scheduled inside `useLayoutEffect` will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

[Here](https://blog.logrocket.com/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect/) there's a good explanation about `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`. But thinking on class components, it's equivalent to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` because it is the commit phase. That's the phase where changes to DOM are allowed to happen as well as side effects and scheduled updates. Both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` have the synchronous behaviour just like `useLayoutEffect`. `useEffect` is the usual recommended option because it won't block the browser rendering which is better for performance in most cases, being an optimized hook version of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.